# Bad Youtube video quality on Ubuntu 14.04 with NVIDIA card

Tags: video, google-chrome, youtube

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with an NVIDIA GTX 960 and the latest drivers. When I watch HD video on Youtube it has really poor quality, while HD videos from disk look normal with VLC. Tested it with several videos in HD which look good on my Chromecast. Chrome is also updated to the latest version.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean?

The screenshot you posted shows [colour banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding) and bad [deblocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deblocking_filter) here on a Windows machine running Firefox in that dark and low complexity scene too. Some other scenes like [9m49s](https://youtu.be/eJDSi_ZXp0E?t=9m49s) appear acceptable for the pretty low quality of the video. That's exactly how bitrate starving video looks like and what the encoder does.

Here is mediainfo from the 720p file that I downloaded to my computer at home:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=60
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 30mn 11s
Bit rate                                 : 1 318 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 6 991 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.057
Stream size                              : 285 MiB (87%)
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-12-18 19:12:58
```

1318 Kbps at level 3.1 is way below typical [recommendations](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/videoencodingh264/) (2496 Kbps/ HQ 3072 Kbps) for 720p content and even low for the higher and more efficient levels. I doubt that YouTube can be blamed for the bad quality of this video, it must have had bad quality to begin with when it was uploaded.

I'm always impressed to see such results when there is Handbrake out there as a good example of a no frills, easy to use and fast x264 configuration with acceptable image fidelity (crf20).

Comment: ok, i see... seems like there are a lot of vids out there which are below typical recommendations. thanks for your detailed answer!